Chandelier will only work with one type of bulb?
I have a chandelier that takes 6 candle bulbs. I was replacing a lightbulb and it kind of popped, now the chandelier will only work with the three remaining bulbs that were opposite of the pop. BUT, these three lightbulbs will work in any of the six spots for bulbs, but only these three bulbs. I have tried four different brands of bulbs, and nothing lights up except those three bulbs that were on the chandelier when it "popped".
What in the heck do I do?

All 6 light sockets work with one brand of bulb, while 3 of them will work with any brand and the other 3 will only work with the one brand? That does, indeed, sound odd. Maybe [edit] to include a list of brand/model numbers that you've tried.

Are the old bulbs incandescent and the new ones LED? Is the switch controlling the chandelier a simple switch or a dimmer or something else?

About the only thing that should make sense, is the three old bulbs have a tiny longer base, and newer bulbs are a bit shorter, so not contacting the centre post.  Turn off the light with the breaker(not just the switch), and carefully pull the the centre post up/out a bit.  A 1/6 to 1/8 inch.

Likely @crip659 has answered the question. I've also enlarged the drop of solder on the center of edison-base lamps ("bulbs").

I have no idea if the old ones are incandescent- that's an excellent question. I didn't realize that would make a difference. The last 2 boxes are LED, I'll try an incandescent. The brands are Philips and a generic one. The dimming knob is on the wall. Thank you so much for your help!
